# Testing an elixir function

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a `Product` schema which has a `UPI(unique product identifier)` eg. `A985748BNG6784C`. This is an autogenerated unique product identifier.

I have a function `upi_generate()` which calls another external function `gen_nano_id()` to generate this random unique id.

If by chance, the id generated by `gen_nano_id()` has already been generated, the function `upi_generate()` calls itself recursively till the time `gen_nano_id()` generates a unique id. Thus generating a unique `UPI`.

`gen_nano_id()` can sometimes return duplicate ids and for that purpose I have written the below code with recursive call.

```
  def gen_nano_id() do  //external function
      Nanoid.generate(10, "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
  end

  # TODO: write test case for this
  def upi_generate() do // required function
      upi = "A" <> gen_nano_id() <> "C"

      case get_product_with_upi(upi) do
         nil ->
            upi 
         _ ->
            upi_generate()
      end
  end

  // Check if product with UPI already exists
  defp get_product_with_upi(upi) do
      from(p in "snitch_products", select: p.upi, where: p.upi == ^upi) 
      |> Repo.one()
  end
```

Now, I have to test the id regeneration logic for duplicate ids.

My testing approach involves following logic.
Create a two products with duplicate `UPI` and try to reach the `_` part of the case comparison.

For this purpose, I have mocked(I don't control the behaviour of this function) the `gen_nano_id()`.

Now, the problem that I am facing is mocking results in creation of always the same ids no matter what and I go in an infinite loop.

I am not able to figure out a way to reach the `exit condition(nil)` part of case comparison with this mocking approach of `gen_nano_id`.

Comment: Why dont you use the UUID module if you need unique keys, there is no such problem with it, you get always unique keys https://hex.pm/packages/uuid

Comment: @fad3d because I want to customize generated uuids in a way that they should be composed of just numbers and capital alphabets.

Answer (score 3):

There is great writing by José Valim [Mocks and explicit contracts](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2015/10/mocks-and-explicit-contracts/). It says

> always consider “mock” to be a **noun**, never a verb

---

That means you should not mock *the generation function*. You’d better create *a generator* and mock it.

Somewhat like that:

```rb
defmodule Generator do
  @callback gen_id :: integer()
end

defmodule NanoGenerator do
  @moduledoc "Used in dev/prod"
  @behaviour Generator

  @impl true
  def gen_id() do
    get_nano_id() # external function or whatever
  end
end

defmodule TestGenerator do
  @moduledoc "Used in test"
  @behaviour Generator

  use Agent # to store state
  @ids ~w|foo foo bar|

  @impl true
  def gen_id() do
    id = # get the counter from Agent, and increase it
    @ids[id]
  end 
end
```

Now you are all set to return *whatever you want* from the generator.

Comment: Here what you suggested is an approach to redefine gen_id() function for tests and control its behavior for TestGenerator module. But what I want is to test the condition where upi_generated is duplicate without changing the function behavior.

Comment: I never suggested redefining anything (e. g. because your code **does not have `gen_id` function at all**.) What I suggested is to isolate the interoperation with an external resource (NanoWhatever,) wrap `get_nano_id` into your own `Generator` and mock it. That is the preferred way of doing this in Elixir.